# Where to place the I18N message properties for a custom (cm:storeSelector) aspect in Alfresco Share?

Tags: internationalization, alfresco, alfresco-share

I enabled the cm:storeSelector aspect in Alfresco Share 4.1.x, as described in the "Alfresco Administrator Guide" (pg. 281).

I tried adding these messages

```
aspect.cm_storeSelector=Store Selector
cm_storeSelector=Store Selector
```

both under

```
/shared/classes/alfresco/messages/slingshot.properties
```

and

```
/shared/classes/alfresco/extension/webclient.properties
```

This is my **share-config-custom.xml:**

```
<alfresco-config>

   <!-- cm:content type (existing nodes) -->
   <config evaluator="node-type" condition="cm:content">
      <forms>
         <!-- Default form configuration for the cm:content type -->
         <form>         
            <field-visibility>
                <show id="cm:storeName" />            
                </field-visibility>               
         </form>
      </forms>
   </config>

   <!-- Document Library config section -->
   <config evaluator="string-compare" condition="DocumentLibrary">
      <!--
         Used by the "Manage Aspects" action

         For custom aspects, remember to also add the relevant i18n string(s)
            cm_myaspect=My Aspect
      -->
      <aspects>
         <!-- Aspects that a user can see -->
         <visible>
            <aspect name="cm:storeSelector">                  
                <title>Store Selector</title>
            </aspect>
         </visible>
        </aspects>
   </config>   

</alfresco-config>
```

Problem is: the aspect name does not show in the Alfresco Share UI ("Manage Aspects" Dialog) - instead it only shows the string `aspect.cm_storeSelector` on the right hand side:

[image]

while it shows fine on Alfresco Explorer:

[image]

**I am wondering where to place the I18N strings correctly for Alfresco Share.**

Comment: Share and the Repo use different files for i18n, so that's not all that surprising. Have you ensured that your Share tomcat is configured to load classes from the `shared/classes` directory?

Comment: @Gagravarr I have added a malformed context xml to /shared/classes/alfresco/extension/, where it throws an error. However, when I place the context xml in folder /shared/classes/alfresco/messages/, no error is thrown at startup time. So I guess, the messages folder is not read, or at least no xml files from there.

Answer (score 1):

Just putting the messages into (a custom) alfresco repository message bundle should be enough to make the translations appear "everywhere" - in share as well.

The key is to follow the name mapping convention.

Have a look at `alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/messages/content-model.properties`

where it reads:

```
cm_contentmodel.aspect.cm_titled.title=Titled
cm_contentmodel.aspect.cm_titled.description=Titled
```

which corresponds to `alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/model/contentModel.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.alfresco.org/model/dictionary/1.0 modelSchema.xsd" -->
<model name="cm:contentmodel"
...
<aspect name="cm:titled">
```

A similar mapping convention applies to properties, types and associations as well. Examples of those can be found across those three files as well.

Comment: Thanks. I had looked at other properties files before and how aspects use the labels in general (and the naming convention of the message keys). Based on that I tried to adjust it accordingly for my aspect, but the messages are still not loaded. I have added an entry "cm_contentmodel.aspect.cm_storeSelector.title=Store Selector" to content-model.properties both under the shared/classes/alfresco/messages/content-model.properties; I had also tried adding it to the original content-model.properties file of Alfresco and restarted Alfresco - but the label still doesn't show.

Comment: Are you sure that Tomcat is loading things from where you're putting your files? To test, put an invalid context xml file in there, and make sure it barfs on startup. If it doesn't, then you know it isn't reading from that folder!

Comment: @Gagravarr I have added a malformed context xml to /shared/classes/alfresco/extension/, where it throws an error. However, when I place the context xml in folder /shared/classes/alfresco/messages/, no error is thrown at startup time. So I guess, the messages folder is not read, or at least no xml files from there.

Comment: But what's also strange: I had even added the messages into the original Alfresco alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/messages/content-model.properties (not under shared) and restarted, and the label still does not show.

Comment: well, you have to use the country (+ language) properties file, e.g. your-model_en.properties or your-model_en_US.properties

Comment: Alfresco does indeed not care about context xml in /shared/classes/alfresco/messages. Put that context file in shared/classes/alfresco/extension and define beans of class org.alfresco.i18n.ResourceBundleBootstrapComponent and org.alfresco.repo.dictionary.DictionaryBootstrap using your model/messages. Have a look at core-services-context.xml for reference.

Comment: @alfrescian Country suffix is optional, if no country suffix is provided, the app usually looks for the fallback properties without a country suffix. Would be surprised if Alfresco wouldn't handle it this way like any other Java app.